# Python Regex: Findall with most number of groups

Tags: regex, python-2.7

Let's say I have a string like this:

```
"(1) This is the first one. (2) This is the second one. (3) This is the third one."
```

And I want to use python 2 regex to capture the items like this:

```
"(1) This is the first one."
"(2) This is the second one."
"(3) This is the third one."
```

Right now I've been trying this:

```
re.findall(r'\(\S\).*',string)
```

But I'm getting it back as one result:

```
"(1) This is the first one. (2) This is the second one. (3) This is the third one."
```

What might be the solution here?

Comment: Use `re.findall(r'\(\d+\).*?(?=\(\d+\)|$)',string)`

Comment: What if your string was this `This is (1) one This is (2) one This is (3) one` ?